# Adobe AIR : Worker can't load file

Tags: actionscript-3, file, air

I have an issue with Workers in AIR : when I try to open a file in a non-primordial Worker, I get a Security error. When I try the same code in the primordial Worker, it works well.
I load another swf and pass its bytes when creating the second Worker.

First, I tried with URLLoader (code in 2nd worker) :

```
// Loading XML test
var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(new URLRequest('app:/config/generator/galaxy.xml'));
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, function(evt:Event):void
{
    // Trace
    CEThreadDebugger.log(XML(loader.data).toString());
});
loader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, function(evt:IOErrorEvent):void
{
    CEThreadDebugger.log(evt.text, CEThreadDebugger.ERROR);
});
loader.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, function(evt:SecurityErrorEvent):void
{
    CEThreadDebugger.log(evt.text, CEThreadDebugger.ERROR);
});
```

I get this error :

```
[LOG]ERROR->Error #2048: Security sandbox violation: app:/SombresCieux.swf cannot load data from app:/config/generator/galaxy.xml.
```

Then I tried with File :

```
var file:File = File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath('config/generator/galaxy.xml');
var stream:FileStream = new FileStream();
stream.open(file, FileMode.READ);
var xml:XML = XML(stream.readUTFBytes(stream.bytesAvailable));
stream.close();
```

And I get this error (my code is in _mainToWorker method) :

```
[LOG]INFO->Error #0 : SecurityError -> file
SecurityError: file
    at flash.filesystem::File$/initAppResourceDir()
    at flash.filesystem::File$/get appResourceDirectoryPath()
    at flash.filesystem::File$/get applicationDirectory()
    at generator::Generator/_mainToWorker()
    at engine.generic.system.concurrency::CEThreadMain/Evt_mainToWorker()
```

I noticed that the error comes from this line alone :

```
var file:File = File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath('config/generator/galaxy.xml');
```

So it works in the primordial Worker (main app), but not in the threads...
Can't the Workers access system's files nor load any file ? It's a quite huge limitation...

Thanks for the replies !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> public function createWorker(swf:ByteArray,
>   **giveAppPrivileges:Boolean** = false):Worker

giveAppPrivileges:Boolean (default = false) — indicates whether the worker should be given application sandbox privileges in AIR. This parameter is ignored in Flash Player

Comment: Thanks for you answer, I figured out and was going to answer it myself. ^^